# How to properly use services with hybris1905?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

Im trying to follow the guide for Hybris123 version 19.05, but when creating new services I get a problem where the spring framework does not recognize my service.

I tried to change the neme of the variable but honestly Im not sure what to do.

The errorIm getting is "org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAllDecorators' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [concerttours.service.impl.DefaultBandService] for bean with name 'defaultBandService' defined in class path resource [concerttours-spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

The code Im using in spring is:

```
   <alias name = "defaultBandService" alias = "DefaultBandService"/>
<bean id = "defaultBandService" class = "concerttours.service.impl.DefaultBandService" >
    <property name = "bandDAO" ref = "bandDAO" />
</bean>
```

And when I use the IDE for looking a file with the name DefaultBandService it recognizethe service that Im trying to use but the spring framework does not. In the service tried to use a spring Tag like component but it didnt work.

I expect spring to recgonize the bean and let me run the hybris server

Comment: Class name *concerttours.service.impl.DefaultBandService* not look correct. Classes generally started with com/org/net. Re-check class name and package.

Answer (score 0):

Use your IDE to look for the class(i.e **DefaultBandService**).

Check the package of the class(most probably the first line of the file).

Make sure that the package is specified correctly in your spring xml File.

Make sure that the class is in the same extension as the Spring file. If it is not, then a dependency needs to be added in **extensioninfo.xml**.

Run "ant clean all" and start the Server again.